# Is it possible to have a protected swagger?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

Do I need to have a protected swagger hub where only application users can advise and would like to know if it is possible?

The best option for me would be to be able to have the swagger hub within my front-end application and that only logged-in users have access to this screen and respectively to the json generated by the api on the back-end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The best option for me would be to be able to have the swagger hub within my front-end

Bear with me, as a lot of this is expositional for the sake of clarity.

Swaggerhub is a webservice where you can host Swagger API documents. It's like a combo of SwaggerUI, Swagger Editor, and Swagger CodeGen, but on a remote site. While inexact, you may consider the following `git -> github as swagger -> swaggerhub`. So you can't exactly have swaggerhub in your frontend.

SwaggerUI is a tool you can use in a spring boot project to share your API info directly from your project, which is probably what you want for your purposes. Once you add the [spring fox swagger](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2) dependencies to your project, you can see the Swagger UI by visiting `http://localhost:8080/your-app-root/swagger-ui/`, where you change it to fit your server address.

Swaggerhub provides the option to control swagger document privacy. While I don't think this is what you want exactly, it is worth mentioning as an alternative. [Check out this short guide from their official documentation.](https://app.swaggerhub.com/help/apis/public-and-private-apis)

If you'd like to implement Swagger UI in your project, [here's a great guide](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api) that even includes some security config. By combining Swagger UI with Spring Security, you can host a swagger page that is only available to certain logged-in users based on your access policy.